# Dynamic grid layout in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I get the json with the header values as category.
I need to split those category as displayed in the image attached[image]

Can any one suggest how to achieve this view using recyclerview
?

Comment: You can use Grid layout recyclerview under recycleview.
In top recycleview you will set category and under each category you will set grid layout

Comment: Yes i know as you can in the picture i have to add a header also in between

Comment: Maulik Patel : can you explain this

Comment: In Main recycleview childview will have one textview which will display category and other element Recycleview again.
You will create another adapter for 2nd recycleview and you can call 2nd recycleview adaper from bindview holder of first rcycleview.
I have done same earlier but i dont have code now

Comment: So you are telling me to create 3 recyclerviews for it

Comment: 2 recycleview.
1st is for category and it contains recycleview.
2nd recycleview will have recycleview grid layout as we are doing normal listing.

only you have to do is calling 2nd recycleview adapter on bindview holder of first recycleview

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create multiple `RecyclerView` as it can be done with a single one. You should create one `RecyclerView`. Inside its item's custom layout, your should add `RadioButton`, `TextView` and 'GridView' and 
you should use `GridView` inside your list item as following

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
    />
```

It will have three columns as needed and `height` as `wrap_content` so that it can be expanded as needed.

Comment: Did not get you

Comment: have you created RecyclerView? please share that part of your code

Answer (score -1):

1. First take one parent `Recyclerview` Which will consist of other `RecyclerView` as you need.
2. Create main `adapter` which will handle parent `RecyclerView` in which your sub `RecyclerViews` will be loaded as `RecyclerView` items.
3. Create adapter for sub `RecyclerView` which will assign these grid items.
4. Set `layout` of main `RecyclerView` as `Vertical` by `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` and in sub `RecyclerView` layout should be a `GridLayout`.
5. For `layout` item of main parent `RecyclerView` should be a `layout` file with a simple `RecyclerView` in it, and for sub `RecyclerViews`, `layout` should be this item you want.